# Mono WCF Rest Service With Multiple Contracts "no endpoints are defined in the configuration file"

Tags: rest, wcf, configuration, mono, endpoint

I want to host a WCF Rest Service with multiple contracts via mono each implemented in a separate partial class. I read many posts on similar issues, yet there was no solution for mono. I incorporated or at least tested all suggestions I could find and by now my code looks a lot like other solutions, yet does not work.

The application runs successfully on my local machine but throws an error once I deploy it via mono.

> Service 'MyWebServiceEndpoint' implements multiple ServiceContract types, and no endpoints are defined in the configuration file.

Here is one of the endpoints with the contract. All the others are very much like this one. They all are a partial class MyWebServiceEndpoint implementing another contract.

```
namespace MyServer.MyEndPoints {        
    public partial class MyWebServiceEndpoint : INotificationEndpoint {

        public string GetNotifications(int limit) {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface INotificationEndpoint {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string GetNotifications(int limit);
    }
}
```

My App.config looks like this. I removed the IP and port, as they are the server address.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="MyServer.MyEndPoints.MyWebServiceEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="WebService.EndPoint">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://ip:port>"/> 
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="/message"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="MyServer.MyEndPoints.IMessageEndpoint" 
              behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior"/>
    <endpoint address="/music"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="MyServer.MyEndPoints.IMusicEndpoint" 
              behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior"/>
    <endpoint address="/notification"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="MyServer.MyEndPoints.INotificationEndpoint"                   
              behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>        
    <behavior name="WebService.EndPoint">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WebBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

I open the service in C# like this.

```
WebServiceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(MyWebServiceEndpoint));
WebServiceHost.Open();
```

The Error message I receive on mono is:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: Service 'MyWebServiceEndpoint' implements multiple ServiceContract 
types, and no endpoints are defined in the configuration file. WebServiceHost can set up default 
endpoints, but only if the service implements only a single ServiceContract. Either change the 
service to only implement a single ServiceContract, or else define endpoints for the service 
explicitly in the configuration file. When more than one contract is implemented, must add base 
address endpoint manually
```

I hope you have some hints or someone knows how to solve the issue. Thank you already for reading up to here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Mono, Does the Mono support `Webconfig` file? I advise you to add the service endpoint programmatically.

```
class Program
    {
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:21011");
            using (WebServiceHost sh = new WebServiceHost(typeof(TestService),uri))
            {
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITestService), binding, "service1");
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, "service2");
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb;
                smb = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                if (smb == null)
                {
                    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
                    {
                        HttpGetEnabled = true
                    };

                    sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                }

                sh.Opened += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("service is ready");
                };

                sh.Closed += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("service is closed");
                };

                sh.Open();

                Console.ReadLine();
                sh.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITestService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string GetData(int id);
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string Test();
    }

    public class TestService : ITestService,IService
    {
        public string GetData(int id)
        {
            return $"{id},";
        }
        public string Test()
        {
            return "Hello " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Result.
[image]
According to the official documentation, we had better not use `Partial class`.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/multiple-contracts
Besides, we could consider launching multiple service host for every service implemented class.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thank. Using WebConfig did not solve it so far. But I found some further information following your answer and also a working example, which does something similar to what I aim for. I also assumed that partial classes might be one of the issues, but also with one service and one endpoint I still receive errors. Yet, I am working on a solution based on the example I found. Will keep this up to date if I get it done.